# Java: String Comparison between FileOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, stringbuilder, dataoutputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a piece of code that writes to a file using a `DataOutputStream` wrapped around a `FileOutputStream`, and writes to a string using a `DataOutputStream` wrapped around a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, both using the `writeDouble()` method.

I then try to read from the file and compare what is read from the file, to the string,(`BufferedReader` wrapped around a StringReader wrapped around b(ByteArrayOutputStream).toString(), and `BufferedReader` wrapped around a `FileReader`) and get the same result.

Even though

```
System.out.println(StrRead1.toString())
```

and

```
System.out.println(StrRead2.toString())
```

print the same thing in the terminal, when I compare the two using

```
(StrRead1.toString().equals(StrRead2.toString()))
```

they are never equal.(Str1 and Str2 being `StringBuilder`s)

Can somebody give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: they might look visually the same, but one might have trailing white space, a line feed etc.

Comment: it could be trailing spaces. Use StrRead1.toString().trim().equals(StrRead2.toString().trim());

Comment: Try `System.out.println("[" + StrRead1.toString() + "]");` (and the same for 2).  This is a good way to identify most (but not all) of the characters that may cause this issue.

Comment: It could be easier to spot the problem if you put more of your code in the question.

Comment: Why are you creating `String`s instead of using `FileInputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` and comparing byte for byte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of writeDouble() is binary. You have no business trying to turn the result into a String, or read that data with a Reader. Use an InputStream and compare the bytes. Or use a DataInputStream and compare the result of readDouble() in each case.

But I really have no idea why you're doing this. writeDouble() is writeDouble(). It does the same thing, regardless of what output stream it's connected to.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Must be rusty, because now that I've taken a good look, it shouldn't have been that hard. Just used a readDouble() to read in from the file and compare the result to a generated binary string, like above.